# Lambda expression with comparisons of string and datetime using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I must do a comparison with a string and a date in the same lambda expression, but I get these errors:

- Delegate `System.Func<FatturaPA_ERP.Contratto,int,bool>` does not take 1 arguments
- Cannot convert lambda expression to type `string` because it is not a delegate type
- Operator `==` cannot be applied to operands of type `string` and `System.Collections.Generic.List<char>`

Here is my code :

```
_listContratti = _db.Contrattoes
                    .Where(a => ((a.PIva.ToLower() == PIVA.ToList()) && (a.Data >= _dt)))
                    .OrderBy(c => c.PIva)
                    .ToList();
```

Where `PIva` is a `nvarchar`, `Date` is a `Datetime` and `_dt` is `DateTime _dt = new DateTime(2015, 06, 11)`

Comment: `a.PIva.ToLower() == PIVA.ToList()` looks very odd to me. You're comparing a lower-case string a `List` of some type?

Comment: It would really help if you didn't use *quite* so many brackets - what's wrong with `Where(a => a.PIva.ToLower() == PIVA.ToList() && a.Data >= _dt)` for example? (I completely agree that it's odd to compare a string with a list, mind you...)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot compare a `List<T>()` to a `string`, they are 2 different [data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type).

Try converting the list to a string first, then you can compare two strings.

```
`((a.PIva.ToLower() == PIVA.ToList().Aggregate((a,b) => a = String.Concat(a,b));`
```